# Get Full Path for uploaded Image

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, file-upload

I am trying to get the full path of an uploaded image to access in servlet and then store in mysql database, I have tried several methods but everytime I get null value, need help with examples. Thanks

Here is what I am doing

```
       ----- In JSP -----
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 50px; height: 20px;"></div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
        <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><span></span><input id="myFile" onChange="showFileName()" runat="server" type="file" /></span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showFileName() {
        var fil = document.getElementById("myFile");
        var file = fil.value;
        fil.setAttribute("name", file)

    }
</script>

    ------ In Servlet -------
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String image = request.getParameter("file");

    System.out.println(image);

    ProductDAO pd = new ProductDAO();

    pd.insertProduct(image);

    doGet(request, response);
}

 ----- In DAO -----
 public void insertProduct(String d)
 {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO product (Images) values (?)";

    try {

        PreparedStatement statement = theCon.prepareStatement(sql);
        File file = new File(d);

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        statement.setBinaryStream(1, inputStream, (int) file.length());

        int row = statement.executeUpdate();

        theCon.commit();

    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            theCon.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Aren't there enougth tutorials on the net ?? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html   http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-file-upload-example-with-servlet-30-api

Comment: Assuming element `myFile` is an `<input type="file">`, your JavaScript code is changing the `name` attribute, which means that the posted value is not called "file" anymore, so `getParameter("file")` will find nothing and return `null`.